# Can not access GCE instance via external IP

Tags: python, flask, google-compute-engine

I created a instance on GCE and started a python Flask hello-world script running on port 5000. Port 5000 is whitelisted in firewall settings.

Pinging the external IP was successful, but when I tried to access, I got this error:

"Failed to connect to 104.154.87.175 port 5000: Connection refused"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
app.run(host=0.0.0.0)

For example 192.168.1.1 is your machine ip. 192.168.1.0 is the entire subnet your machine is in. And 0.0.0.0 is for all existing IPv4 networks around the world.

Comment: Can you explain why it will work ?

Comment: This serves the app through all the network.  For example 192.168.1.1 is your machine ip. 192.168.1.0 is the entire subnet your machine is in. 0.0.0.0 is the entire network.